# Get the previous date from employee record with reference for the current date using 2 sheets [Google Sheets]

Tags: function, google-sheets

I have an excel file and need to update them to Google sheets. The problem is I cannot convert the functions in my excel to Google sheets.
Can anyone help me get the correct function for previous date from employee record with reference for the current date using 2 sheets [Google Sheets]

Excel function:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,Sheet2!K:K/(Sheet2!K:K<X2)/(Sheet2!A:A=A2),1)
```

I have tried QUERY function but I haven't found any examples online that could get the correct result.

From the 1st sheet 'Main Data to LOAD' I need to adjust column 'G' and 'I' it to get result.
Sheet 2 Employee record history used for checking the correct date for the first sheet.

Here is a mock sheet so anyone can try: (Kindly make a copy first for testing, I have an extra copy but just to be safe. Thanks)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16pZgf7igkt27Ep8a94-5t1M8KEW5wxP5uzSdHCNx_k4/edit?usp=sharing

Let me know if more information is needed.

Kind regards,

Comment: AGGREGATE function does not exists in Google Sheets, There is another relevant question can you explore that https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/121867/using-aggregate-formula-on-google-sheets-finding-the-correct-result-based-on-3

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Which values have to go to 'G' an 'I'? Have you considered doing it with apps script?